# Google GSA empty result for language selection

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have an question regarding the result sets for a GSA request.
When I search with a language restriction and the result should be empty, the GSA still returns all results without language restriction.

Is there any possibility to disable this behaviour, because it seems not very user friendly, to show results which have explicit excluded in a language the user possibly don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a default behaviour well documented in GSA documentation . If you wish to have any customization , i guess you will have to request this feature . I hope you have seen this section right from the GSA language filters documentation .[image]

Comment: Yes, I've seen that but the web search don't have such a fallback, which seems not appropriate especially when I request a specific language.
I hoped for an configuration option deeply hidden in some confiuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411?hl=en

if possible you can disable it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes